# Trimming in Spring Data command generated

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a method for get users by username

```
Page<User> findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCaseAndEnabledTrue(String username, Pageable pageable);
```

However, there is a problem if someone enters white characters before or after the name. As in Java there is a `trim ()` method, whether you can add something similar to `trim` to the command to delete white characters when checking in Spring Data.

Comment: is this not java? `username` is a string, just call `trim()` on it before you pass it to that method.

Comment: Yes. However, I would like to know if you can do it in the method name.

Comment: No, that is not possible in Java.

Comment: you can trim the name before passing it to spring data repository..you should validate your input before passing it to data layer..or it will be open to many security risks

Comment: Spring Data [supports only a limited set of keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for generating queries. There is no keyword that will trim down strings, so, no, trimming cannot be performed simply through the method name.